# How to check if a widget is removed from a QGridLayout?

Tags: qt, qt5, signals-slots

I created a subclass of QComboBox that adds a delete icon on it. When clicked, the widget delete itself with `.deleteLater()`. I use these comboboxes inside a `QGridLayout`.

I would mark the current document as changed when one of these comboboxes is removed, but I can't find any event or signal about it.

Comment: There is [`QObject::destroyed`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed) signal.

Comment: Another option, since you are subclassing QComboBox, you can emit your own signal from your subclass when a change occurs (whether another item has been selected or when the user clicks the delete icon)...

Comment: @thuga: thank you, it works and it's quite general (apart the fact I have to connect it every time I create a combobox).